# fatal error in master.cf when restart postfix

Tags: postfix, spf, spoofing

I follow a guide to prevent spoofed emails in my mail server

first I installed **postfix-policyd-spf-perl**

> apt-get install postfix-policyd-spf-perl

second I added this lines to the smtpd_recipient_restrictions in the main.cf

> check_policy_service unix:private/policy

and finally I added these lines at the end of /etc/postfix/master.cf

> policy unix - n n - - spawn
>  
>   user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/perl /usr/sbin/postfix-policyd-spf-perl

but when restart postfix it returns the following error:

> /usr/sbin/postconf: fatal: file /etc/postfix/master.cf: line 147: bad
>   field count

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found the error

The lines add to master.cf must be in this way:

```
policy unix - n n - - spawn<br>
  user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/perl /usr/sbin/postfix-policyd-spf-perl
```

A leading space is necessary in the second line